# Azure CLI not found on path Stack

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-managed-identity

I'm working on an azure python app function of queue trigger type that create a VM once triggered.
To do so, I need to work with the **ManagedIdentityCredential()** in order to acquire a credential object using CLI-based authentication but I'm having this error:

**Result: Failure Exception: CredentialUnavailableError: Azure CLI not found on path Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.9/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py"**

Here's the piece of code that causing the error:

````
import base64
import azure.functions as func
import requests
from azure.identity import ManagedIdentityCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient

credential = ManagedIdentityCredential()```
````